# What resources does .NET Windows Service use?

Tags: .net, windows-services

Does a process intensive Windows Service that handles heavy requests use more CPU, more RAM or both or neither?

In a nutshell, this Windows Service uses a 3rd party component in processing requests that take a long time to complete.

Anyone? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "process intensive" refers to something that eats a lot of CPU cycles.

It may or may not also happen to use use a lot of RAM, but there is no direct relation between these two. A process can take a long time to complete without being *process intensive* in the above sense, for example if the computer is waiting on some kind of I/O like a disk or internet connection, or some kind of shared resource.

Comment: I guess I have to rephrase the question. How do I find out if my windows service is using more CPU or more RAM or both?

Comment: Use 'Task Manager' to see what resources it is using.